# OpenGL custom rendering pipeline: Perspective matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, 3d, lwjgl, perspectivecamera

I am attempting to work in LWJGL to display a simple quad using my own matrices. I've been looking around for awhile and have found a few perspective matrix implementations, these two in particular:

```
[cot(fov/2)/a 0          0                  0]
[0            cot(fov/2) 0                  0]
[0            0          -f/(f-n)          -1]
[0            0          -f*n/(f-n)         0]
```

and:

```
[cot(fov/2)/a 0          0                      0]
[0            cot(fov/2) 0                      0]
[0            0          -(f+n)/(f-n)          -1]
[0            0          -(2*f*n)/(f-n)         0]
```

Both of these provide the same effect, as expected (got them from [here](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/perspective-projection-matrix/) and [here](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Quad_with_Projection,_View_and_Model_matrices#Projection_matrix), respectively).  The issue is in my understanding of how multiplying this by the modelview matrix, then a vertex, then dividing each x, y, and z value by its w value gives a screen coordinate. More specifically, if I multiply either of these by the modelview matrix then by a vertex (10, 10, 0, 1), it gives a w=0. That in itself is a big smack in the face.  I conclude either the matrices are wrong, or I am missing something completely. In my actual test program, the vertices don't even end up on screen even though the camera position at (0,0,0) and no rotation would make it so. I even have tried many different z values, positive and negative, to see if it was just a clipping plane. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: After a lot of checking over, I've narrowed down the problem I am facing. The biggest issue is that the z-axis does not appear to be remapped to the range I specify (n to f). Any object just zooms in or out a little bit when I translate it along the z-axis then pops out of existence as it moves past the range [-1, 1]. I think this is also making me more confused. I set my far plane to 100 and my near to 0.1, and it behaves like anything but.

Comment: I already multiply in that order in my vertex shader. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both of these provide the same effect, as expected

While the second projection matrix form is very standard, the first one gives a different effect. If you have `z==1` and `w==0`, the projection will be:

Matrix 1: `-f/(f-n) / -f*n/(f-n) = f / f*n = 1 / n`

Matrix 2: `-(f+n)/(f-n) / -(2*f*n)/(f-n) = (f+n) / (2*f2n)`

The result is clearly different. You should always use the second form.

> if I multiply either of these by the modelview matrix then by a vertex
>   (10, 10, 0, 1), it gives a w=0. That in itself is a big smack in the
>   face

For a focal length `d` the projection is computed as (ignoring aspect ratio):

```
x'= d*x/z = x / w
y'= d*y/z = y / w
```

where

```
w = z / d
```

If you have `z==0` this means that you want to project a point that is already in the eye and only points beyond `d` are visible. In practice this point will be clipped because `z` is not within the range `n` (near) and `f` (far) (`n` is expected as a positive constant)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on that point, but that still doesn't solve the whole issue. I will add a bit to the question to clarify

Comment: the near and far planes are in camera space. a `z` between near/far will be in range [-1,1] after perspective transform and projection (w division). a `z` outside that range will be clipped